# Building a Sega Genesis Classic Portable - What kind of display?

Tags: display, sega-genesis, portable

I am trying to make a portable version of a Sega Genesis Classic. (See this example on [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X2PE3Oqqt48).)
I'm wondering what kind of display module I would need to solder to the board for this project.

Comment: Even though it's for playing retro games, the Sega Genesis Classic is actually a modern device. You may find more appropriate advice if you ask this question on https://electronics.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Answer (score 5):

In the video you linked (at 01:12), I notice that this device has the standard yellow and white connectors for composite video and audio. Many cheap portable LCD TVs support this kind of input, and are often battery powered, too.